# Autofill every 31 cells in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet structure

```
A1

Cat001
useless
useless
.
.
.
31 times useless
.
.
.
empty row
Cat002
useless
useless
.
.
.
31 times useless
.
.
.
empty row
```

And so on, so what im trying to do is a Macro that start a A1, Autofill with the value on A1 the next 31 rows, skip a row, take the value on A33, Autofill the value on A33 the next 31 rows and so on

Comment: well i tried recording the macro and decipher how it works
im talking of 90k rows approx thats why i wanted to do this with a macro

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) Hint: Google for "For Do Loops in VBA" as well

Comment: Yes i tried with various ways
using Offset 
using a variable to increase 
and tried an Index but didnt understand how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
dim rng as range

set rng=activesheet.range("A1:A32")
do while application.counta(rng)>0
    rng.value=rng(1).value
    set rng=rng.offset(32,0)
loop
```